# I can't login. It keeps Saying Error Logging in eventhough I have entered the email and password as I input in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

The Email/Password sign-in provider's status has always been "Enabled" since the start. but it's still giving me the same error. Even from the Authentication in Firebase shows that 
1. Connect your app to Firebase -> Connected (green check) 
2. Add Firebase Authentication to your app -> Dependencies set up correctly (green check)

I have tried to login with email and password that I entered into the Firebase but I still can't login.
It shows me Toast:

> Error Logging in :(

I have been trying to find solutions from the internet. This is my current code:

```
04-14 18:46:05.238 9631-9631/com.adrian.projectadrian E/Login Error: signInWithEmailAndPassword
    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzey.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeo.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

```
package com.adrian.projectadrian

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        login_btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            login()
        })
    }

    private fun login() {
        val emailTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.email) as EditText
        var email = emailTxt.text.toString()
        val passwordTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.password) as EditText
        var password = passwordTxt.text.toString()
        if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            this.mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, home::class.java))
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Logged in :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Login Error", "signInWithEmailAndPassword", task.getException())
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Logging in :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill up the Credentials :|", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result is that it can direct me to home page.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: The error you now get is quite explicit: you'll need to enable the provider in the Firebase console for the code to work. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666264) to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was download another

```
google-services.json
```

and replaced it to Dir

```
app
```

and change to this

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

in my build.gradle (Module: app) and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit we can now see that this is the error message:

> The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

So you haven't enabled the provider that you're trying to sign in with. The solution is to go to the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers) and enable that provider.

---

Original response:

If a `Task` failed, it contains an exception with details about the failure. You should log that exception to find out why the sign-in fails.

```
this.mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, home::class.java))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Logged in :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Log.e("Login Error", "signInWithEmailAndPassword", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Logging in :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

With the above code you can find the exception in the logcat output of your app.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sorry for the late reply edit

Comment: The Email/Password sign-in provider's status has always been "Enabled" since the start. but it's still giving me the same error.
Even from the Authentication in Firebase shows that
1. Connect your app to Firebase -> Connected (green check)
2. Add Firebase Authentication to your app -> Dependencies set up correctly (green check)

Comment: Thank you for helping me and the time Frank :)